# How to convert a pandas list row to numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has two columns:

```
name, [sizes]
```

Example

```
one, [1,2,3]
two, [4,5,6]
```

I would like to convert values to array for further processing.

```
x_data = list(set(df.name.values))
y_data = [df.query('name == @h').sizes.values  for h in x_data]
```

This returns:

```
[array([list([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object), array([list([4,5,6])], dtype=object)]
```

Is there a way to flatten this out and have it as a simple array[] instead of array[list[]]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tolist()`:

```
np.array(df['sizes'].tolist())
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

**Note** it only works if all the lists are of the same size within the column. For different sizes, we would get something like:

```
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6, 7])], dtype=object)
```